# How to use KDE or Gnome hardware/network detection in another desktop environment?

Tags: gnome, kde, desktop-environments, fluxbox

I like to run light Window Managers, like Fluxbox, not for performance just because I find them simpler to configure and they fit better my working style. But having automatic hardware and network detection is also very convenient.

Is there any way I can have that same Gnome or KDE functionality without having to use the whole environment itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, install components of gnome/kde and/or lightweight alternates.

For networking, take a look at wicd

What do you want in terms of hardware detection ? If you want a graphical interface for installation of graphical drivers (nvidia) you can try jocky or jocky-gtk. The graphical drivers tend to be a one-time installation so not sure if you want these tools.

There are tons of other small applications such as tint2, nitrogen, pcmanfm, etc.

On Fluxbox / openbox you can install single gnome / kde applications

See :

http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/a-5-minute-guide-to-fluxbox/

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lightweight_Applications

Comment: What I would like is basically network and hardware detection on the fly and maybe autoinstallation of required plugins, etc. Like autodetecting any USB device, wifis, etc.

Comment: wicd and jocky-gtk would be good first starts.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the eg. gnome networkmanager.

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

Use `nm-applet` to start the network manager, or add the `nm-applet` command into your `~/.xinitrc` to automatically load the applet.

Good luck!